# Carregar arquivo.properties

Tags: java, log4j, propriedade

Estou com dificuldades em ler um arquivo.properties. Criei uma classe a parte com um método estático. Porém, ele lança uma exceção e retornar null.

Segue abaixo o meu código.

```
public class LoadLog4jProperty {

    protected static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    public static void loagLog4jProperty() {

        String logPath = "back/src/main/resource/log4j.properties";
        Properties propertyFile = new Properties();

        try {
            propertyFile.load(new FileInputStream(logPath));
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(propertyFile);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.warn("Log não configurado corretamente: " + e.getMessage() );
        }
    }
}
```

Estrutura do projeto:

[image: Estrutura do projeto:]

- O que estou fazendo de errado??
- De que outra maneira posso ler um arquivo.properties??

Comment: Por gentileza poste a estrutura do seu projeto, provavelmente o caminho `back/src/main/resource/log4j.properties` apontado está incorreto. Tente apenas `/resource/log4j.properties`

Comment: @ngueno postei a estrutura

Comment: Gabriel, tente a sugestão do @ngueno, mas antes acerte o nome da sua pasta "resource", o correto é "resources".